# Visual Studio 2013 temporarily freezes after rebuild all

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

After clicking rebuild all, I get the message saying "there were build errors etc" and visual studio freezes completely for like 45 seconds, then returns back to normal.

I have tried to solve this by deleting all sorts of temporary files generated by VS as well as disabling graphic acceleration.

I also uninstalled the VS then re-installed.  Nothing helped.

I am running Windows 7 x64 with Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This looks like a hard issue to solve, because it can be a lot of things. Have you included pdb symbols from external resources? Is debug set to `Just my code`, have you tried disabling the toolbox?

Comment: This is an environmental problem, you need to get your machine stable again.  Start by disabling anti-malware and firewall.  Cloud storage utilities are next.  Start killing processes from Task Manager one by one until you find the evil-doer.

Comment: I also have this problem, my CPU usage goes up to 50-70% like it's working on something, then after a minute or so it comes back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

part of my assemblies was at another computer location and there was an access trough UNC between the computers.

I found out that the UNC has a huge latency between the computers.

now every time VS is doing compilation it's going to check all assemblies links at project and this is what make it work so slow.

you can move the ref assemblies to your local PC
or fix the latency.